# Get edtitext value from fragment with onClick method

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, android-edittext, fragment

I wanted to create an app with a `Fragment` that contains three `EditText` and a button. I wanted the button to save the values of my `EditText` in SQLLite. For the moment I just try to get my `EditText`s' values and show them with a `Toast`.

The problem I have is that my toast only print the value of my first `EditText` and I do not understand why my two other values aren't read.

Here is my activity code :

```
public class CreatePolicy extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_policy);

        CreatePolicyFragment createPolicyFragment = new CreatePolicyFragment();

        if (findViewById(R.id.createPolicy_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null)
                return;

            createPolicyFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.createPolicy_container, createPolicyFragment).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

My fragment code :

```
public class CreatePolicyFragment extends Fragment {
    EditText name_choice;
    EditText protocol_choice;
    EditText priority_choice;
    Button button_create;
    Button button_cancel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_policy_fragment_layout, container, false);

        name_choice = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.input_name_choice);
        protocol_choice = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.input_protocol_choice);
        priority_choice = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.input_priority_choice);
        button_create= view.findViewById(R.id.button_create);

        button_create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String qosName = "";
                String qosProtocol = "";
                int qosPriority = 0;
                qosName = name_choice.getText().toString();
                qosProtocol = protocol_choice.getText().toString();
                qosPriority = Integer.parseInt(priority_choice.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Policy name : "+ qosName + "\nPolicy protocol : "+ qosProtocol + "\nPolicy priority : "+ qosPriority, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

And here are my layouts :

Activity layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment android:name="map.android.com.pushqospolicy.createPolicy.CreatePolicyFragment"
        android:id="@+id/createPolicy_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="map.android.com.pushqospolicy.createPolicy.CreatePolicy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_name_choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:labelFor="@+id/input_name_choice"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qos_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/policy_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/input_name_choice"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/input_name_choice"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/input_name_choice" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_protocol_choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:labelFor="@+id/input_protocol_choice"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_name_choice" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qos_protocol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/policy_protocol"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/input_protocol_choice"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/input_protocol_choice"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/input_protocol_choice" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_priority_choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:labelFor="@+id/input_priority_choice"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_protocol_choice" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qos_priority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/policy_priority"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/input_priority_choice"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/input_priority_choice"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/input_priority_choice" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_create"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="@string/button_create"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="@string/button_cancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm a beginner with android and fragments... Could someone please help me with that problem ?
Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: tryLog instead of text and check logcat

Comment: Just curious, are you entering some values for other two edittexts before the click of the button? :D If yes, you should wrap the value of `qosPriority`(i.e `String.valueOf(qosPriority)`) in the string you're passing as second parameter to `makeToast()`.

Comment: Oups.. :) Yes it was just for testing. But even without that it doesn't work

Comment: @RémiDelfosse Everything looks fine,debug at each point and test properly.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Here is my logcat : 

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: map.android.com.pushqospolicy, PID: 30342
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:533)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
    at map.android.com.pushqospolicy.createPolicy.CreatePolicyFragment$1.onClick(CreatePolicyFragment.java:48)
...

Comment: Line 48 of my fragment is this one : qosPriority = Integer.parseInt(priority_choice.getText().toString());

But I also tried to remove my third edittext and try only with the first two (which get string values) and the problem is the same : my toast only return the value of qosName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the constraint layout,I don't why this issue is coming with constraint layout.I am also new to constraint layout,will research and let you know more about this issue.
Use LinearLayout or RelativeLayout to fix this issue.Tested its working.
For testing find the following reference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qos_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="policy_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_name_choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qos_protocol"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="policy_protocol" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_protocol_choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qos_priority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="policy_priority" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_priority_choice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_create"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="button_create" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:text="button_cancel" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunatly it didn't solve my problem... The app don't crash anymore, but I still don't get my edittexts values.

For these values written in my edittexts :
   Name : azerty
   Protocol : azerty
   Priority : 1234

My toast returns this : 
    Policy name : azerty
    Protocol : [nothing]
    Priority : 0

Comment: Thanks. But this way the `Toast` doesn't return anything

Comment: In fact It only returns qosName and nothing for the two other `EditText`

Comment: Thanks a lot, t works indeed !
Now I just have a display problem due to my fragment that appears multiple time, one below the other... But that's ok, I'll cope with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are appending data in Toast using + and "".
Just use separate String with your data from 3 EditText and pass that String to toast.

```
 button_create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String qosName = "";
                String qosProtocol = "";
                int qosPriority = 0;
                qosName = name_choice.getText().toString();
                qosProtocol = protocol_choice.getText().toString();
                qosPriority = Integer.parseInt(priority_choice.getText().toString());
                String data = "PolicyName: " + qosName + "Policy Protocol: "  + qosProtocol  + "Policy Priority: " + qosPriority;
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), data , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```